# How do I center an image on browser when part of the page is hidden with overflow CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to center an image on a browser using:

```
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
```

However, because the site has a hidden area (an extra 583px wide), using this image centering CSS doesn't center the image exactly. i.e. it currently works like this -  (browser width + hidden width) x 50%... not browser width x 50%.

**[This is the site.](https://robt.info/)** You can view the hidden area by clicking the plus symbol (jQuery animate used to unhide overflow width). I'm currently using **left: 30%;** on the centred image (the penguin and the sausage dog) as a rough estimate of browser size, so it isn't exactly centered.

[image: css image centering]

Is there any way I can add some maths formula to the above css code to compensate for the extra hidden page width?? I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
width; 50%(-583px)
```

What is the best way to center the image (rob towner logo) when the page has a hidden extra width??

EDIT: here is all the css & html that currently exists for the center image - [jsfiddle.net/VVLk9](http://jsfiddle.net/VVLk9/)

Answer (score 1):

can you not do like the following in your script that assigns `left` value to `#author` div when the hidden element is shown.

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
var divWidth = $("#author").width();
$("#author").css("left", (screenWidth - 583 - divWidth)/2);
```

Comment: I will play with this... would be cooler if there was a way do this purely with CSS though...

Comment: I think the way to play it with css would be to wrap the #author div in another wrapper div. and give margin: 0 auto to #author, or text-align: center to the wrapper. (still you have to decide the width of the wrapper using script)

Answer (score 1):

Here, it was little tricky but the main part is this right side is absolutely positioned and brought in when needed. And the content, is basically **centered** `ex 50%` when right side is **hidden** but of **fixed length** `ex 200px` from left when right side is **visible**. It's not as fluid as it may seem. Meaning the content of left main box isn't centered all the time. The width of of main left box dosen't changes so therefore having its content centered would result in it appear as it hasn't responded to the new sidebar which is the effect we didn't want. So it's just some animation which i think works fine in giving illusion of interactivity of content.

**Preview:** http://jsfiddle.net/k6L6R/show

**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/k6L6R/

this is all js code:

```
$('.cont').click(toggleBar);

var state=0, s1=$('.s1').children('div'),s2=$('.s2');

function toggleBar() {

    if (state) { 
        s1.css('left','50%');
        s2.css('margin-left','0px');
        state = 0;
        return;
    }
    s1.css('left','190px');
    s2.css('margin-left','-300px');
    state = 1;
}
```

less stronger effect: http://jsfiddle.net/k6L6R/2/show/

Comment: Thanks for this. Only problem is the slide in effect is only on the homepage :/ on all other pages, the side #wrapper div needs to be visible

Comment: you should probably use different layout system for pages that aren't going to have effect...it'd be easier in long run. use this : http://jsfiddle.net/nBPg2/

Comment: i wrote some js to even further ease it down...it's not very versatile but it's good for your case. http://jsfiddle.net/fxWg7/1493/show/